# Android Java App crashes when using location listener and trying to get coordinates | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locationmanager, locationlistener

my android app crashes when I am trying to get the current location in java. I've watched many tutorials and tried like everything. Does anybody know why the app crashes or is someone having a working solution for getting the coordinates in Java? Thank you guys!
The Main Activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PermissionInfo;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.MultiFactorResolver;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.NotNull;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.location.LocationListener;
public class ZeiterfassungMain extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ZeiterfassungMain";
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDbRef;
    private String userId;
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    LocationManager lm;
    int noOfFixes = 0;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final EditText User = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordTB);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zeiterfassung_main);

        latitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourLat);
        longitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourLong);
        GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(this);

        if(mGPS.canGetLocation ){
            mGPS.getLocation();

        }else{

            System.out.println("Unable");
        }



    }







    public void LogOutClick(final View View) {

        mAuth.signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(ZeiterfassungMain.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();


    }


    public void StartClick(Location location) {
//Check if GPS is enabled

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy;HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        final EditText orttb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OrtTB);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference(MainActivity.LoggedInName + "/" + "Start-" + formatter2.format(date));
//Setting firebase unique key for Hashmap list
        String userId = mDbRef.push().getKey();
// creating user object
        Users user = new Users("Erfassung Gestartet", orttb.getText().toString() + " - ", formatter.format(date));

        mDbRef.child(userId).setValue(user);
    }



    public class Users {

        private String Event;
        private String Ort;
        private String Uhrzeit;

        public Users() {
        }

        public String getEvent() {
            return Event;
        }

        public void setEvent(String event) {
            Event = event;
        }

        public String getOrt() {
            return Ort;
        }

        public void setOrt(String ort) {
            Ort = ort;
        }

        public String getUhrzeit() {
            return Uhrzeit;
        }

        public void setUhrzeit(String uhrzeit) {
            Uhrzeit = uhrzeit;
        }

        public Users(String event, String ort, String uhrzeit) {
            Event = event;
            Ort = ort;
            Uhrzeit = uhrzeit;

        }
    }



}
```

The GPSTracker.java Class:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public final class GPSTracker implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    public boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Function to get the user's current location
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Log.v("isGPSEnabled", "=" + isGPSEnabled);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Log.v("isNetworkEnabled", "=" + isNetworkEnabled);

            if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    location=null;
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    location=null;
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}
```

Comment: First-  post stack traces with crashes.  Second-  don't use this GPSTracker class.  Its broken in a dozen subtle ways and while it works sometimes, it will lead to pain and bugs if you try to use it for anything serious.

Comment: Thank you Gabe, the Logcat log says: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
But i did already requested permissions. Sorry but I am new to Java.

Comment: Do you have that permission in the manifest and request runtime permission?

Comment: Yes, I use this to request the permissions at runtime: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
Is this correct?